# Modification to Dijkstra, verification needed

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

Dijkstra algorithm has a step which mentions "chose the node with shortest path". I realize that this step is `unnecessary if we dont throw a node out of the graph/queue`. This works great in my knowledge with no known disadvantage. Here is the code. Please instruct me if it fails ? if it does then how ? [EDIT => THIS CODE IS TESTED AND WORKS WELL, BUT THERE IS A CHANCE MY TEST CASES WERE NOT EXHAUSTIVE, THUS POSTING IT ON STACKOVERFLOW]

```
  public Map<Integer, Integer> findShortest(int source) {
        final Map<Integer, Integer> vertexMinDistance = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        queue.add(source);
        vertexMinDistance.put(source, 0);

        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            source = queue.poll();
            List<Edge> adjlist = graph.getAdj(source);
            int sourceDistance = vertexMinDistance.get(source);

            for (Edge edge : adjlist) {
                int adjVertex = edge.getVertex();
                if (vertexMinDistance.containsKey(adjVertex)) {
                    int vertexDistance = vertexMinDistance.get(adjVertex);
                    if (vertexDistance > (sourceDistance + edge.getDistance())) {
                         //previous bug
                         //vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, vertexDistance);
                         vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, sourceDistance + edge.getDistance())
                    }
                } else {
                    queue.add(adjVertex);
                    vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, edge.getDistance());
                }   
            }
        }
        return vertexMinDistance;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tested it? Does it give the correct results for your test cases? To be appropriate for StackOverflow, you should identify any problems with the code and have the question ask about them.

Comment: If you don't remove vertices from the queue, then the queue never becomes empty, and the algorithm will never terminate.  Have you tried executing this code?

Comment: source = queue.poll();

Comment: This will work, but since the vertices will not be processed in increasing order of distance, but in the order of discovery, you will have the problem that vertices will need to be put into the queue multiple times for many graphs, giving this algorithm an (if I remember correctly) exponential worst case running time. Dijkstra avoids this by processing vertices in increasing order of distance, thus ensuring that a vertex never needs to be put into the queue twice.

Comment: `you will have the problem that vertices will need to be put into the queue multiple times` - this is not true. if a vertex is in a map, means it was put in queue, which means I dont put a vertex in queue twice.

Comment: You're right, it won't be put into the queue twice this way; then the problem with the algorithm is that this way, you won't get the correct distances.

Comment: That is true, in the accepted answer I realized my bug. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem 1

I think there is a bug in the code where it says:

```
                int vertexDistance = vertexMinDistance.get(adjVertex);
                if (vertexDistance > (sourceDistance + edge.getDistance())) {
                    vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, vertexDistance);
                }
```

because this has no effect (vertexMinDistance for adjVertex is set back to its original value).

Better would be something like:

```
                int vertexDistance = vertexMinDistance.get(adjVertex);
                int newDistance = sourceDistance + edge.getDistance();
                if (vertexDistance > newDistance ) {
                    vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, newDistance );
                }
```

### Problem 2

You also need to add the adjVertex into the queue using something like:

```
                int vertexDistance = vertexMinDistance.get(adjVertex);
                int newDistance = sourceDistance + edge.getDistance();
                if (vertexDistance > newDistance ) {
                    vertexMinDistance.put(adjVertex, newDistance );
                    queue.add(adjVertex);
                }
```

If you don't do this then you will get an incorrect answer for graphs such as:

```
A->B (1)
A->C (10)
B->C (1)
B->D (10)
C->D (1)
```

The correct path is A->B->C->D of weight 3, but without the modification then I believe your algorithm will choose a longer path (as it doesn't reexamine C once it has found a shorter path to it).

### High level response

With these modifications I think this approach is basically sound, but you should be careful about the computational complexity.

Dijkstra will only need to go round the main loop V times (where V is the number of vertices in the graph), while your algorithm may need many more loops for certain graphs.

You will still get the correct answer, but it may take longer.

Although the worst-case complexity will be much worse than Dijkstra, I would be interested in how well it performs in practice.  My guess is that it will work well for sparse almost tree-like graphs, but less well for dense graphs.

Comment: fixed the bug (not reflected fix on stack overflow). Great answer, but could you please explain "while your algorithm may need many more loops for certain graphs." ? Even my queue loops equally as Dijkstra ?

Comment: You are quite right, I hadn't spotted that you were not readding vertices to the queue.  I have edited the answer to describe that as problem 2.  In other words, your original algorithm is indeed faster than Dijkstra (but sometimes incorrect).